# How to allow a text box to show suggested values already stored in a table in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to find a way that a text box input in a form in microsoft Access 2016 can show suggested values in a table/column; similar to how microsoft excel can auto-fill an entry after typing a couple letters if it has already been typed onto the spreadsheet. I've looked into combo boxes but from what i've found they limit you to only entering information that's already in the database.

In essence, what I want is for textboxes in my form to act like excel cells in the way that they can potentially autofill entries - to save typing it out multiple times.

Comment: Comboboxes allow adding new values to the base table right from main form and allow entering values not from the database, check properties on Data tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a combo box and set the record source with the appropriate sql string?  This will be much simpler than trying to hack your way into a text box doing the same thing. IF you really need it this way let me know and im sure i can whip something up pretty quick :)

[image]